# (Python 2.7) variable returns "[ ]" instead of desired results

Tags: python

The variable returns "[ ]" instead of desired results.

```
S = set(['a', 'b','d','z','x','y'])
collect = set()
step = set([''])
while step:
   step = set(a+b for a in step for b in S if len(a+b) == 6)
   collect |= step
print sorted(collect)
```

Also how could I make this a loop that plays through the combinations instead of a set?

Comment: I'm getting an `IndentationError`. Could you double-check your formatting?

Comment: `itertools.combinations` will give you combinations ... what's your end goal here?

Comment: Is this the same indentation as in your code?

Comment: The indentation was fixed and it still did not work. Do you know how i could use itertools.combinations   to get a loop that loops through all the combinations one by one and perform an action on each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what "desired results" means, here's your second problem:

```
>>> len('' + 'a')
1
```

(First problem is indentation.)

---

So...wtf are you doing with this line?

```
step = set(a+b for a in step for b in S if len(a+b) == 6)
```